# Concatenating two files to a new location

Tags: unix

I am trying to concatenate two files "File 1" and "File 2" to a new location using linux.
And I wrote the following code.

```
cat File 1 File 2 > /Desktop/Data/Sample_File
```

But it is not taking the path while concatenating.
Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote the names of the files if they have spaces. Also, use `>>` instead of `>` if you want to append with new data:

```
cat "File 1" "File 2" >> /Desktop/Data/Sample_File
```

If you want to set the output file, do:

```
outputfile="/Desktop/Data/Sample_File/my_file"
cat "File 1" "File 2" >> $outputfile
```

And of course make sure it is not a directory. To check it, do:

```
[ -d "/Desktop/Data/Sample_File" ] && echo "it is a dirrrr"
```

All together, you can do:

```
outputfile="/Desktop/Data/Sample_File/my_file"
[ ! -d "/Desktop/Data/Sample_File" ] && cat "File 1" "File 2" >> $outputfile
```

Comment: Yes, arguments need to be quoted here. And also I've never seen '/Desktop` folder in the filesystem root. I guess it should be `$HOME/Desktop`. Why using the `>>`? `>` Should work here.. Isn't it?

Comment: Nopes. Its not working. Its showing an error saying /Desktop/Data/Sample_File is a directory.

Comment: @Rachel then it means that `/Desktop/Data/Sample_File` is a directory. Do `cat "File 1" "File 2" >> /Desktop/Data/Sample_File/one_file`

Comment: If it is a directory, you cannot `cat` file data to it. Pick a filename that is not the name of an existing directory or remove the directory.

Comment: Thanks. But can i give the path like that as i mentioned above for concatenating.?

Comment: What do you mean, @Rachel ? You can do `cat "File 1" "File 2" > $new_path` if you firstly define `new_path=/your/path/file`